# How to make a custom EaseOut function that speeds up?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, easing

I have a mouseover function that basically causes a div to move up/down. This uses an interval timer and is animated to make it smoother.

How can I make the animation speed up each interval to match the final ease out speed? Basically, when you mouseover, it should keep getting faster and faster but remain smooth animation.

```
function StartAnimation() {
        var oldMarginTop = $('#MyDiv').outerHeight(true) - $('#MyDiv').innerHeight();
        var newMarginTop = oldMarginTop + 100;
        $('#MyDiv').animate({ marginTop: newMarginTop }, 500, 'linear');
    }
}

$('#SomeObject').bind('mouseenter', function () {
    this.iid = setInterval(function () {
        StartAnimation();
    }, 500);
}).bind('mouseleave', function () {
    this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
    //FinishAnimation();
});
```

Comment: Use a timeout and decrease the time value for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the interval.

What you're describing, I think, is `easeIn` which you can get with [this jQuery plug-in](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) (along with various alternative easing functions). The page also includes a demo to allow you to test the each of the easing functions to find the one which best suits your requirements.

You should then be able to use the function you choose directly as a parameter in your call to `jQuery.animate`.

Comment: Sorry I left out the important part: I'm repeating the same function. Basically, as long as the user is moused over the arrow, I keep adding to the margin. I've tried using the jquery easing plugin, but each time I add to the margin it gets fast, but then slows down at the start again at the start of the next animation  (eases into it).

Comment: Yeah I wondered if I was missing something ;). Is there a limit to the size of the margin?

Comment: Basically, it's a scroller for a fixed nav bar. It stops as soon as the element is wholly visible on the screen. I'll look into it though. Maybe I can calculate how much it needs to scroll. For now, I just set the easing to "linear".